# Clean Url Error 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Just wanted to customize Error 404 in my htaccess. The problem is when the user goes to Error 404 page. The URL is not clean compares to others. URL looks like these index.php?page=page-not-found .. How can I make it http://example.com/page-not-found.htm or http://example.com/page-not-found/ ??? By the way, have a look on my codes.

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/index.php?page=page-not-found

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.htm$ /website/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/lesson/([^/]*)\.htm$ /thesis/index.php?page=$1&lesson=$2
```

Any idea guys? By the way, thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Remove `http://` from your `404` directive to avoid server making a full redirect for 404:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=page-not-found

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.htm$ /website/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/lesson/([^/.]+)\.htm$ /thesis/index.php?page=$1&lesson=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument it should work with external urls too.

Comment: It works with external URLs but that will be full redirect not internal rewrite.

Comment: So the rewrite engine won't work because of it being a full redirect? And it does normally? (The OP is asking to show his url as example.com/page-not-found/ instead of example.com?page=page-not-found. Prettifying the URL.

Comment: @Spork If you use external then you get a redirect (that's not what OP wants here). Also, you get a 302 before the 404 and that's really, really, really bad for search engines. Most of the time, never use external for 404

Comment: I agree with that, and I agree that this answer provides an improvement. My question was, out of interest, if this also solves the actual question: does it prettify the URL this way? Or will it just go to index.php?page=page-not-found.

Comment: Since OP's urls are already in pretty format, we can assume that @anubhava's answer is enough because 404 page's content is shown and url's browser stays unchanged. OP's didn't want his old 404 url to be shown but it was because of `http://` in `ErrorDocument`

Comment: @Spork: This will only internally rewrite 404 URLs to `/index.php?page=page-not-found`. Since there is no redirect hence browser will not show `/index.php?page=page-not-found` URL.

Answer (score -1):

```
Please try this one.First remove your extensions from all files and try this one

    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]+)$ /p.php?photo=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(Joe|Mao|Napoleon|Gandi)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Copy/paste code from somewhere. It has nothing to do with OP's question